# MySQL join two tables into one

Tags: mysql, join

I have two imaginary tables:

1.
People

```
id, age
1, 25
```

2.
Names

```
id, people_id, type, value
1, 1, 'first', 'John'
2, 1, 'last', 'Doe'
```

How can I join the two tables so I'd get this result:

```
id, age, first, last
1, 25, 'John', 'Doe'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        a.Age,
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.type = 'first' THEN b.Value END) `First`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.type = 'last' THEN b.Value END) `Last`
FROM    People a
        LEFT JOIN Names b
            ON a.ID = b.people_id
GROUP   BY a.ID, a.Age
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4c90b/1)

Otherwise, if you have unknown values on column `type`, a dynamic statement is much more preferred.

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN b.type = ''',
               type,
               ''' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS ',
               CONCAT('`', type, '`')
               )) INTO @sql
FROM Names;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  a.ID,
                            a.Age, ', @sql , '
                    FROM    People a
                            LEFT JOIN Names b
                                ON a.ID = b.people_id
                    GROUP   BY a.ID, a.Age');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4c90b/5)

Comment: What I'm trying to avoid is having to join the names table twice to the people table. Is the first example something that I should definately use instead of double join?

Comment: where is the double join?

Comment: In your example there is no double join. I meant was that is your example better than this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4c90b/13/0

Comment: oh i rather use the first query than the query in the fiddle you showed.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for general information on how to join data from different tables. It is called inner join.
Reference can be found [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you,

Method: 1

```
 select p.id, p.age, n.type as first, n.value as last from People as p, Names as n where p.id = n.people_id
```

Method: 2

```
 select p.id, p.age, n.type as first, n.value as last from People as p LEFT JOIN Names as n ON p.id = n.people_id
```

Comment: There's no first or last columns in names table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, p.age, n.first, n.last
FROM People p
JOIN Names n 
ON p.id = n.people_id;
```

Comment: There's no first or last columns in names table.

Comment: `select p.id, (select type from names n1 WHERE p.id = n1.people_id and n1.type='first'),
(select type from names n2 WHERE p.id = n2.people_id and n2.type='last') from people p;`